# I am trying to make a command where i can enable/disable my Welcome Event on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So ive successfuly created a welcome message for users when they join the server which functions properly but, I want to make a command which allows me to turn the Welcome event off or on How can I do this.

```
@commands.Cog.listener() 
async def on_member_join(self, member):        
    guild = discord.utils.get(member.guild.name)         
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='general')  
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} welcome to **{guild}**! Dont be useless.")
```

Comment: Just Add One More Command which receives a input of `true or false` from a user and store it in a variable about whether to display welcome message or not. Then Use A If Case inside the welcome message  function to check if the variable is `true` then send the message. If Its `false` then nothing should happen.

Comment: you need global variable i.e `show_welcome =  True` and in code use `if show_welcome: ... code...`. If you change this global variable to `show_welcome = False` then it stop show it. And it may need other command to change this variable.

Comment: eventually you can use function [remove_listener](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_listener) and `add_listener` to remove `on_member_join` and later add back `on_member_join` - but it still may need other command to control it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def turnoff(ctx):
    sendwelcome = False
```

And then at the start of what you have just put

```
if sendwelcome = False:
    return
```